# is glue embolization the last frontier in Intracranial aneurysms research?

Tags: blood, neurology, stents

I very very recently started researching the field of intracranial aneurysms (ICA) and I have this question about that glue or gel that some people talk about.

To me, who I am just learning the basic stuff, it seems that if such a thing goes out to the medical market, then it's game over for the treatment of ICA. And it actually makes sense, according to the coiling principles, that one would think of something more stable throughout time to put into the saccular structure in order to neutralize it.

Assuming of course that such a material be safe for the tissue, and that it have such properties that wouldn't mess with the blood flow, and that would remain stable within the sac, then it seems that the problem of IAC treatment boils down to a problem of biomaterials and chemical engineering.

However, no matter how exciting this might seem, from the almost 182.000 papers on [pubmed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/) about aneurysms, there are less than 1000 talking about this method. Likewise, on youtube, the videos regarding such an exciting potential therapy are bizarrely few and most of them were published more than 10 years ago.

Comment: I did a _very_ brief PubMed search and found a few newer articles, but it does appear that interest in this treatment has waned in recent years. I would take that to mean it's not proven itself to be the last frontier in ICA treatment. So I think the answer to your question as stated is simply "no." But are you actually asking why it's not? That would seem to me to be the more interesting question.

Comment: Normally, such a reasonable invention should have revolutionized the field and probably it should have "put the other devices out of business". It hasn't, as you also saw. There has to be a reason for that. That too, by itself, is quite interesting. 
Of course the question of utmost importance to me is the following: assuming that such a matterial is invented and has all the necessary properties needed. Is there anything left for other research fields to work on?

Comment: For instance, MDs will keep doing the exams they do and will have to guide the cable to the area of interest in order to place the material. Anything else after that, seems just a matter of optimization: how to perfection this specific application. No other application is going to be needed. Ok, at most, let's say a stent might be needed, too to keep it in place until the perfect material is found.
Am I right the way I see it? BTW my thoughts here are too simplified, and almost simplistic, only because I need to understand the big picture

Comment: A quick google search tells me this is a common procedure. The choice of which procedure to use depends on a number of factors such as position of the aneurysm, size, treating surgeon etc.